# Library for C# to read Excel 2007 xlsm file?

Tags: c#, xlsm

Does someone know library for C# to read xlsm file (Excel 2007 with macro) ?

I've downloaded EPPlus, it read xlsx files but it has an error New line format.

Thanks

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302801/epplus-throws-datavalidations-exception-requested-value-date-was-not-found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Infragistics.Excel](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/infragisticsexcel.aspx#Overview)** can read and write .XLSM files.

Note, that this library requires .NET Framework 3.0 to support Microsoft Excel 2007.