# EPPlus throws DataValidations exception "Requested value 'date' was not found." when trying to save xlsm

Tags: c#, excel, exception, openxml, epplus

I'm attempting to make changes to a customer-supplied **.xlsm** file (a C# application will fill with data from a web-form and submit to a CMS) using [EPPlus.](https://epplus.codeplex.com/)

But on package.Save(name) -- or packagae.SaveAs(name) -- an exception is thrown by the DataValidations collection:

```
2011-11-28 14:17:51,380 [9] ERROR app.ExcelConverter - System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'date' was not found.
   at System.Enum.EnumResult.SetFailure(ParseFailureKind failure, String failureMessageID, Object failureMessageFormatArgument)
   at System.Enum.TryParseEnum(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase, EnumResult& parseResult)
   at System.Enum.Parse(Type enumType, String value, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at OfficeOpenXml.DataValidation.ExcelDataValidationCollection..ctor(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.get_DataValidations()
   at FItoExcelCore.ExcelConverter.RunSample(String filePath) in \path\to\class.cs:line 32
```

Even attempting worksheet.DataValidations.Clear() throws the same exception, and  this is without any changes to the file:

```
        try
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(output))
            {
                package.SaveAs(output);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
```

I do not have this behavior in an excel file that I create from scratch, but I need to use the supplied file.

Don't know if it's significant, but I'm working in the .Net 4 Framework, and it's an 1.01 MB .xlsm file. The file saves/saves-as fine (even with new data) from within Excel.

NOTE: apparently **.xlsx** files work just fine, but the the .xlsm format contain VBA macros that can't be saved in the .xlsx format, so the file-type cannot be converted.

Comment: an unanswered SO question also suggests that EPPlus doesn't work for xlsm files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336803/library-for-c-sharp-to-read-excel-2007-xlsm-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, within sixty seconds of posting I find new information online.

There is a [discussion](https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/203915) at the EPPlus codeplex site that suggests that "**there is no real support for [xlsm files] in the component.**"

The may be the source of the problem.

Comment: I haven't been able to get official confirmation of this this within the EPPlus forums, so I'm leaving this open a little longer.

Comment: I got a response from somebody at EPPlus that there was a bug, but the provided fix still didn't work (in fact, wouldn't even open at all, much less get to saving). https://epplus.codeplex.com/discussions/281085

Comment: So I'm going with the de facto answer of "EPPlus doesn't [fully] support .xslm files."

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of EPPlus?

They fixed this issue March of 2011. It had to do with ValidationTypes being case insensitive.

See:
http://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/13246

**Edit**:
You can also try saving it as .xlsx if xlsm isn't supported.

Comment: I'm using EPPlus 2.9.0.1 from (I believe) Tue May 31 2011 at 3:00 AM -- I just downloaded it on Wed, Nov 23.

Comment: Hmm..well that's definitely an enum error..same as you'd get with regular enums in C# when trying to find a match for an item that's not in the enum. Are you using 'date' anywhere in your code? I believe EPPlus uses 'datetime' for the Excel cells.

Comment: Not using it anywhere. Can't even find it in the existing file (other than labels for fields where a date should be entered).

Comment: you can't save the VB project (macro-code that is additional to the .xlsm format) in the .xlsx format.

Answer (score 0):

As Ed Wrote i have donwloaded the last version of EPPlus which is from  Jan 31 2012,and it worked very well with its validation. The excel im reading and writting is a .xlsx format.

Comment: you can't save the VB project (macro-code that is additional to the .xlsm format) in the .xlsx format